# GWT Highcharts API legend does not appear

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I want to add a  legend to my Highstock:

```
        Legend legend = new Legend();
        legend.setAlign(Legend.Align.RIGHT);
        legend.setBackgroundColor("#CCCCCC");
        legend.setShadow(true);
        stockChart.setLegend(legend);
```

I am using the GWT Highchart API, which is a wrapper for Google Web Tookit:

http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/

But somehow the legend never appears, whereas the graph appears :/
Anybody can help?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the behavior you're having in my app and it all worked fine for me. Perhaps something is blocking the area of canvas where the legend is displayed. Could you please show the minimal viable example where the problem always appears?